# I can't figure out the height for a UITextView for a footer...before TableView frame is set. I'm stumped

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uitextview

So I'm struggling with a bit of an issue here.  I am trying to put a `UITextView` as a footerView for a `UITableViewController`.

However, since depending on what data the UITextView has (it is set up in `viewDidLoad`), it can be different text at runtime.  So I can never know how tall the `UITextView` will be.  It's width is the same as the UITableView though.

I figured if I get the width of the `UITableView` and the text of the `TextView`, I can calculate the size it is supposed to be.  So I wrote this code for `(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section:`

```
    //get the width of the tableView.
    CGFloat width = self.tableView.frame.size.width;

    //if it's bigger than the screen for some reason, or zero, set it to the screen's width.
    if (width > [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width || !width)
        width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 10;

    //get the text from the textView, including attributes.
    NSAttributedString *attributedText = _textView.attributedText;

    //figure out the size it's supposed to be.
    CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){width, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               context:nil];
    CGSize size = rect.size;
    size.height = ceilf(size.height);
    size.width  = ceilf(size.width);


    //return the height, plus a little padding to be safe.
    return size.height + 10;
```

So here's the ugly thing.  At the time `tableView:heightForFooterInSection:` gets called, the `TableView`'s frame is some wacky number like 600.  The calculation is wrong, usually too small, and the `UITextView` is cut off by the low height that gets returned.

However, if I *rotate* the device, this code gets run again, and it *works*!  So I know this code is good...*if run later*.

If I do a `[tableView reloadData]` at any point, it also fixes the `TableView`.  It's only on first load that it gets cut off.

If I could figure out a way to reload the `tableView` *once* after it finishes loading, that'd fix it, but I'm not sure how to do it and it's kind of a hack-y solution anyway.

Can anyone help me figure out better logic for this?  I've been stumped for some time.

Comment: Did you try calling this code inside of `-viewDidAppear:` ? Or simply call `[tableView reloadData]` inside of `-viewDidAppear:` ?

Comment: I did think of this! Oddly, it still has the same result.  I have to rotate and rotate back to fix it.

Comment: If the width of the `tableView` is equal to the width of the screen; I would use the width of the screen as reference or calculate the width of the `tableView` relative to the width of the screen as a percentage to ensure the return is the same every time.

Answer (score 0):

Reload the table view in `-[UIViewController viewDidLayoutSubviews]`. By that point, the entire view hierarchy will (or at least *should*) have its final, valid geometry.

Also, footer views are different from section footers. There is only one footer view, and it's a property on the table view. I wouldn't put that text sizing code in that delegate method, as that's meant for section headers explicitly.

Finally, what is the table view's **bounds** height at that point?

Comment: it's a section footer, not the table footer, sorry.  When I put [tableView reloadData] in viewDidLayoutSubviews, I get an infinite loop.

The entire thing method is: 
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    
    [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: That makes sense, actually, since the table view IS a `UITableViewController`'s root view. This is one reason why `UITableViewController` is generally not a good view controller to subclass. Is the table view's bounds correct?